# How to create hbase bundle for jboss fuse

Tags: hbase, jbossfuse

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hbase.
How to create hbase bundle for jboss fuse..

Comment: You need to better explain what you ask about

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use hbase in JBoss Fuse, you can install the camel-hbase feature which install hbase for you.

In the JBoss Fuse shell type

```
features:install camel-hbase
```

Comment: thanks for reply Claus Ibsen.I created an camel route which stores file in hbase.But when i am deployed to jboss fuse it is giving hbase.default,xml is to for or older version.I am using hbase 0.94.11 version.